# Magento 2 addImageToMediaGallery strange behavior

Tags: magento-2.1, product, cli

I've got something strange happening when **replacing products images** from **CLI** in Magento2.

The way I do it is the following :

I check if the image already exists in the product (based on the file name).

If ok, I backup information from the image.
I add the new image.
I delete the old one
If I got attributes like small, base or thumbnail, I affect it to my new image (the last inserted).

But sometimes, the `$product->addImageToMediaGallery` fails without rising any exception. Which is strange.

I just add to add/update thousands of images before launch, and we add lots of them missing.

What happened is that the `$product->addImageToMediaGallery` failed, so I deleted the existing image, leaving the product without any image !

So I added a test with counting the number of entries in the Media Gallery before and after the `addImageToMediaGallery`. And then, another strange behavior : the image was, in the end, added to the gallery, but not right away. So my test still shows the same number of entries in the Media Gallery before and after the add, resulting on multiple copies of the image in the product ! (it's in a cron)

My code goes something like this :

```
    $nbImages = 0;

    // Find the other informations (id, position, actif, label) and count

    $images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
    foreach($images as $image){
        $nbImages++;
        if (strpos($image['file'], $nomImage) !== FALSE) {
            $goodImage = $image;
        }
    }

    try {
        $imageTypes = [];
        $product -> addImageToMediaGallery($fullImageName, $imageTypes, TRUE, FALSE);
        $product -> save();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Some personal log function
        $this -> _logs -> addError('Error modifying image '. $fullImageName.' : '. $e -> getMessage());
        return false;
    }


    $productR = $this -> _productRepository -> get($sku);

    $nbImagesAfter = 0;
    $images = $productR->getMediaGalleryImages();

    foreach($images as $image){
        $nbImagesAfter++;
    }

    if ($nbImages == $nbImagesAfter) {
        $this -> _logs -> addError(''Error modifying image '. $fullImageName);
        return false;
    }
```

I use $productR because, even with `$product->save()`, if you call back `$product->getMediaGalleryImages()`, the gallery is *always* unmodified.

Any idea of what happens ? Is there a sure way to know the add worked or failed ? The function return $this, so the product itself.

Thanks in advance.